# Как проверить файл на то, что его содержимым является XML документ?

Tags: c#, wpf, xmlparser, linq2xml

У меня есть схема, при помощи которой я проверяю переданный документ на валидность. Но если я передаю другой файл, текстовый или картинку, то программа загибается еще на этапе открытия. Как вариант, можно открытие обернуть в `Try..catch`, но хотелось бы узнать, есть ли иной способ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оборачивайте открытие в `try`/`catch`.

Все стандатные способы работы с XML выбрасывают исключения при невалидности (в смысле well-formed) документа. Методов `IsWellFormed` нет.

Единственное, что можно улучшить (если вы это еще не сделали) - использовать для валидации именно `XmlReader` c [`ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationflags(v=vs.110).aspx) - чтобы избежать потенциальных проблем с огромными документами, которые "биты" в самом конце.

Comment: Так и сделал. Обернул в `try..catch`. Валидность у меня проверяется не через `TheXDocument.Validate(...`. Тут есть одна проблема. Возможно, мне потребуется в зависимости от причины краха выполнить определенные действия. А тут причины краха я вижу только в `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)`. Не парсить же мне Exception.Message для этого.

Comment: @iRumba из стандартного `XmlException` можно вытянуть только номер строки и столбца. Если нужно больше подробностей о нарушении схемы - придется искать сторонний парсер

Comment: Передаю я в качестве файла картинку, а он мне говорит, что у меня ошибка на 1 позиции 1 строки ))

Comment: @iRumba ну он полностью прав. я бы на вашем месте ограничился сообщением "вы закачали не xml, а черт знает что". выяснять насколько этот "не xml" на самом деле не xml - достаточно бесполезное занятие.

Comment: @iRumba если очень хочется - можно добавить [mime type sniffing](https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/mime-types-sniffing-in-c-sharp/), и как-то разнообразить сообщения. Например, для картинок выводить "вы закачали картинку, а нам нужен xml!". Но практической ценности в этом нет.